# Get public properties that aren’t static with PHP Reflection

Tags: php, api, class, object

I need to use [PHP Reflection API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to get all the publicly accessible properties for a class that **aren’t static**.

In order to get just the public properties that are not static, the only way I could see to do it was to get the IS_STATIC properties and use `array_diff()` to get only the public ones.

Final class looks like this :

```
class foo {
    public static $a;
    public static $b;
    public static $c;

    public $d;
    public $e;
    public $f;

    public function reflect()
    {
        $reflection = new ReflectionClass($this);
        $public = $reflection->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);
        $static = $reflection->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_STATIC);
        $properties = array_diff($public, $static);
        foreach($properties as $property) {
            echo $property->name . "n";
        }
    }

}
```

Call:

```
$foo = new foo;
$foo->reflect();
```

The output from `reflect()` now looks like this :

```
d
e
f
```

> Question : Is there a better way to do this ?

**Note** : My original class is too long! This class is an example similer to mine.

Comment: Reflection is for other use ase, i think you should use `get_object_vars (object $object )` on real object. https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.get-object-vars.php`

Comment: You mean this https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflection.examples.php how to get none statics ?

Comment: Just get all public props and apply `array_filter` with `!->isStatic`

Comment: @u_mulder You mean in an if statement like `if($property->isStatic())` ? Can you give an example please.

Comment: You don't need to use Reflection for this case, `$a = new Foo(); var_dump(\get_object_vars($a));` this works well, you will get all properties of the object that are public and non static.

Comment: @Lounis Thanks I know how to access class property  https://ocramius.github.io/blog/fast-php-object-to-array-conversion/ I need to use reflection.

Comment: @Lounis is correct - you can `print_r(get_object_vars($foo));` and get array of public non static properties without reflection.

Comment: As @u_mulder said you could filter: `\array_filter($public, function ($i) {if (false === $i->isStatic()) {return $i;} } );`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest way is definitely use `get_object_vars`, for your case:

```
print_r(get_object_vars($foo)); 
// outputs
Array
(
    [d] => 
    [e] => 
    [f] => 
)
```

Keys are propertes' names.

But instantiating an instance can be quite heavy. So, you still can use reflection and a little of filtering:

```
public function reflect()
{
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass($this);
    $properties =  array_filter(
        $reflection->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC),
        function ($property) {
            return !$property->isStatic();
        }
    );
    foreach($properties as $property) {
        echo $property->name . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you explain please why its beter than my solution in question ?

Comment: At least because you don't have to use `array_diff`.

Comment: Damn! I need to look into `array_filter()` and `array_diff()` again, got bad memory :) I will give it a try now and see the difference. Thanks

Comment: Ok! in my main class there are some duplicate keys, so I had to use both functions `array_diff()` to find duplicates and then `array_filter()` to get none statics, I am not sure of performance but it does what its asked to do. Thanks a lot.